# Is there a faster way to count an XmlNodeList

Tags: c#, xml

I read a couple of RegEx definitions from an XML the count function requires about 47.3% of the time. Is there a better / faster way to get the job done?

```
private string[] XmlNodesToString(XmlNodeList TagName)
{
    int a = TagName.Count;   //47,3%
    int i = 0;
    StringBuilder sbTemp = new StringBuilder();
    while (a > 0)
    {
        if (TagName[i].InnerText != "null")//11,8%
        {
            sbTemp.AppendLine(TagName[i].InnerText);
        }
        i++;
        a--;
    }
    char[] cSplitDef = { '\n' };
    return (sbTemp.ToString().Split(cSplitDef, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
}
```

I'm glad about any help that I get thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over nodes:

```
private string[] XmlNodesToString(XmlNodeList TagName)
{
   return XmlNodeList.Cast<XmlNode>()
                     .Select(n => n.InnerText)
                     .Where(t => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(t))
                     .ToArray();
}
```

You don't need to get nodes count, then access nodes by index and build string, which later should be splitted.

---

If LINQ is not available to you:

```
private string[] XmlNodesToString(XmlNodeList nodes)
{
      List<string> result = new List<string>();

      foreach(XmlNode node in nodes)
          if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(node.InnerText))
              result.Add(node.InnerText);

      return result.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: The second solution works Thanks :D But with LINQ I get an error ".Select(n => n.InnerText) no definition for inner text" and I do not know why